# How to prove an abelian group $G$ must have an element of $p$, $p$ is a prime divisor of $|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

An exercise:

---

Assume $G$ is a finite abelian group, and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$. Prove that there exists an element in $G$ of order $p$. (Hint: Let $g$ be any element of $G$, and consider the subgroup $\langle g\rangle $; use the fact that this subgroup is cyclic to show that there is an element $h\in \langle g\rangle $ in $G$ of prime order $q$. If $q = p$, you are done; otherwise, use the quotient $G/\langle h\rangle $ and induction.)

---

I don't know how to complete the induction. What I have done is :

---

The order of $\langle g\rangle $ is $t=p_1^{t_1}\dots p_r^{t_r},$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes and $t_i\ge 1$.
Then the order of  $g^{p_1^{t_1}\dots p_i^{t_i-1}\dots p_r^{t_r}}$ is $p_i$.

If $p=p_i$ for some $i$, then we are done.

Else, $G_1:=G/\langle g\rangle $, then $p\Big||G_1|$. Let $g_1$ be any element of $G_1$. Repeat what we have done above. Similarly, define $G_i:=G_{i-1}/\langle g_{i-1}\rangle $. Since $p\Big||G|$, we always can find a cyclic group $G_i=\{ag_{i-1},\dots,a^{p-1}g_{i-1},g_{i-1}\}$ of order $p$, where $a$ is an element of $G_{i-1}$.

---

I am stuck. $a$ is an element of $G_{i-1}$, that is, $a$ is a coset, not an element of $G$.I

1. I don't know whether I am on the direction. If so, what should I do next?
2. If not, what's the right way?

Hope I can get help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems that the induction here should be applied to the number of prime factors (considering multiplicity) of the group order.

Comment: Thanks!!! You did help me ! I misunderstood the hint. Now I can prove it : )